# CakePHP/Croogo: How to search in translated nodes too

Tags: cakephp, croogo

In croogo's search-View from the Nodes-controller the results include only nodes, where the searched term was found on the Node's model fields, but will skip any translated content for the nodes.

I'm trying to override this functionality and add support for translated content as well, but having a hard time to override the search-view without having to override the whole node-controller.

Does anyone has done this before and could give me some advice, as which approach could I take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I ended up doing the following:

- Add a new `SearchController` on my Plugin with a `show`-view, which is an adapted version of the search-View on the `NodesController`.
- Override the `search/*` route with my new view.

In order to search in the translated fields, I came with 2 possible approaches:

1) If using only the paginate for this, then there would be necessary to join the node and the i18n tables, first And then look for the string additionally on the joined fields.

2) Or, first find all distinct nodes with matching content on the i18n table through a query. And then use this list of nodes to add condition of "`OR Node.id in (list_of_nodes)`"

I ended up with alternative 2, and this is how the show-view looks like:

```
public function show() {
    if (!isset($this->request->params['named']['q'])) {
        $this->redirect('/');
    }

    App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');
    $q = Sanitize::clean($this->request->params['named']['q']);
    $results = $this->Node->query(
        "SELECT DISTINCT(foreign_key) FROM `i18n` " .
        "WHERE content LIKE '%" . $q . "%';");
    $node_ids = array();
    foreach($results as $res) {
        $node_ids[] = $res['i18n']['foreign_key'];
    }
    $this->paginate['Node']['order'] = 'Node.created DESC';
    $this->paginate['Node']['limit'] = Configure::read('Reading.nodes_per_page');
    $this->paginate['Node']['conditions'] = array(
        'Node.status' => 1,
        'AND' => array(
            array(
                'OR' => array(
                    'Node.title LIKE' => '%' . $q . '%',
                    'Node.excerpt LIKE' => '%' . $q . '%',
                    'Node.body LIKE' => '%' . $q . '%',
                    'Node.id' => $node_ids,
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'OR' => array(
                    'Node.visibility_roles' => '',
                    'Node.visibility_roles LIKE' => '%"' . $this->Croogo->roleId . '"%',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    // some more stuff ...
}
```